# Docker Swarm load balancing or mesh routing issue

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm, docker-network, kong

I have a single docker node configured as a docker swarm.

I have created an overlay network called main_net which uses encryption.

I have mutiple containers connected to this network. One of which is called kong and runs kong. I have a service called saas_thumbsum_0_0_13 - this has a single container running inside it.

Kong is configured as a reverse proxy for saas_thumbsum_0_0_13, and uses the address saas_thumbsum_0_0_13. This setup was working this morning when I had a service called saas_thumbsum_0_0_12 running, Kong was sending requests to http://saas_thumbsum_0_0_12:80/public without a problem.

I have now created another service 0_0_13 and connected it to the network but kong can not access http://saas_thumbsum_0_0_13:80/public

I have logged into the console of the kong container and ran the following commands:

```
/ # nslookup saas_thumbsum_0_0_13
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      saas_thumbsum_0_0_13
Address 1: 10.0.0.39
/ # nslookup tasks.saas_thumbsum_0_0_13
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      tasks.saas_thumbsum_0_0_13
Address 1: 10.0.0.40 d4c3034462d1.main_net
```

so the service resolves to 10.0.0.39 which I guess is the load balanced ip, and the service has one task with an ip of 10.0.0.40. Seems ok so far.
Now I try and ping the two ip's from inside the kong container:

```
/ # ping 10.0.0.39
PING 10.0.0.39 (10.0.0.39): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.39: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.089 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.39: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.39 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.083/0.086/0.089 ms
/ # ping 10.0.0.40
PING 10.0.0.40 (10.0.0.40): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.40: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.40: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.40 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.091/0.118/0.146 ms
```

I can successfully ping both IP addresses. This seems fine to me as from my beginner level knowldege they should load balance to the same endpoint and the results should not differ.

Now if I try and get the webpage from the load balanced ip it fails:

```
/ # wget 10.0.0.39/public/web/frontend
Connecting to 10.0.0.39 (10.0.0.39:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.0.39): Connection refused
```

Same if I use the service name

```
/ # wget saas_thumbsum_0_0_13/public/web/frontend
Connecting to saas_thumbsum_0_0_13 (10.0.0.39:80)
wget: can't connect to remote host (10.0.0.39): Connection refused
```

same with and without http://

but it works if I go to the task ip:

```
/ # wget 10.0.0.40/public/web/frontend
Connecting to 10.0.0.40 (10.0.0.40:80)
Connecting to 10.0.0.40 (10.0.0.40:80)
frontend             100% |*******************************************************|  1769   0:00:00 ETA
```

But I should be using the service endpoint not the task endpoint!

If the address is load balanced then they both should go to the same target so the result should be the same.

The target container is running nginx and I have checked the config files there but I don't see any kind of source ip restriction. Not sure how I would do this anyway because the ip addresses would be different every time anyway!

So this is broken, wget saas_thumbsum_0_0_13/public/web/frontend should be giving me the page but it is not working.

If anyone can spot my mistake or give me any debugging pointers it would be appreciated.

Some other info that might be helpful:

```
robert@metcaac4:~$ docker --version
Docker version 18.09.3, build 774a1f4
robert@metcaac4:~$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
ac295a4f901c        bridge              bridge              local
5aa2eea87b33        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
3744b0f39195        host                host                local
lffazc510t7z        ingress             overlay             swarm
r8z2bb9idtwt        main_net            overlay             swarm
0ad4a8efa4cc        none                null                local

robert@metcaac4:~$ docker network inspect main_net
[
    {
        "Name": "main_net",
        "Id": "r8z2bb9idtwtyfr20e6u1p2f8",
        "Created": "2019-03-07T20:24:38.553471996Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "2b3b0d5311f23b084a2aa5282f451acb2c6d636b5ceb11926a46ee0a62e3035a": {
                "Name": "code_site2_code_site2.1.bqcsxy73pczsurit07lxmmoru",
                "EndpointID": "c9974c99e83338aa07f17eda56342757bce6a247105eb8fa4afab1b71f8d0366",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:b7",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.183/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "2ed56f6b2b06cbdeed62037cf10e40683b2960b2d53866e22a4080fa7a50a563": {
                "Name": "saas_user_management_0_0_66.1.0092odmxl4er803jhcrad7xhb",
                "EndpointID": "90f6cc3368c1fd0e5ff0be990f7cd0b1a854584eea3cdac3a80c0d535aa94c43",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:f5",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.245/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7059b7eb266a6ad159fab1606b176c23d70f91841fb2635e5e163afa44f78e32": {
                "Name": "kong_kong.1.dr5afpgi5me23p96kub2qmjaq",
                "EndpointID": "0bfc5ece35f5278596b05232cbc5f88deef9c9a6d132d6f54b82b4c7c7e4d4fe",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:b8",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.184/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7e0153b62eab821019b8f0757c842de367a61025e2848c0548c3cb7bd28d2df0": {
                "Name": "code_site2_code_site2_nginx.1.ijxkoaxzrly1b0dkt2ysdot3r",
                "EndpointID": "d776003ee4a98acd9cb1df2d3fe2861f4c8aca9c655a01dac9b371aebc4a6b2f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:27",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.39/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "9cebbcf75312ce906786d722c38c30c85a84ec5b4efbe46656388f49fa50f942": {
                "Name": "saas_user_management_0_0_50.1.9xkwovfqejqerzi5co2mfb5l4",
                "EndpointID": "28cfcbd20723b272f787f1ecea7603b65f1bd48df8dcb89474087d3f5ae77ed7",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:21",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.33/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a44f86449e19ca3a6fc170c3ed997156f0d3db66fece23883c1a3f844714e504": {
                "Name": "kong_dbb.1.l4d1xzqtr4t0thjnf39twfo0j",
                "EndpointID": "a410b8db987fd7eb261865c27dc84905bdfab273ccf20906c7b5a1ba0cbd1ab8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:ad",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.173/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "d4c3034462d106496da5df3449d1da26dd50bcf40e4b954aea0b64a33a88d954": {
                "Name": "saas_thumbsum_0_0_13.1.of39j50gs0d5376nqgtsszx7m",
                "EndpointID": "a10e51cc60c559f9631a0fb883ca00a654bd1c815cc0a4730222be27847a802f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:28",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.40/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "deda51bfbee097093ccb3e5be7ea11aa0648bdc74381f1552fe102b8646343cf": {
                "Name": "dockerregistry_dockerregistry.1.rty0eoy404m870f6qkpla9c9z",
                "EndpointID": "ff64d38ae4f932b7567cb0b5417df0cb8eef12e46572636a40d59da37511eff9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:ae",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.174/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e117e90a37cacbdbfc2768e2c77512b1c967e268718884f0372d63c1f6b79cbd": {
                "Name": "code_site2_code_site2_nginx.1.dihdw4g5n8i20pbb7nfwwi6ud",
                "EndpointID": "620d3c5de8169a380cb3c2e2caa91e18c91a1d4cf244900e5ea4912941e9c4c8",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:ac",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.172/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-main_net": {
                "Name": "main_net-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "d4b3747a3701b05f716f47295132939bed6f68c566fbf5ab50b70071e2d5cd0d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4097",
            "encrypted": ""
        },
        "Labels": {},
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "1a2559b7bdb0",
                "IP": "78.31.105.225"
            }
        ]
    }
]



robert@metcaac4:~$ docker service ls
ID                  NAME                            MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                                         PORTS
miqimzjmh0qe        code_site2_code_site2           replicated          1/1                 metcarob/phpfpm_for_drupal:0.0.6              
bgixg86fhaqs        code_site2_code_site2_nginx     replicated          1/1                 nginx:1.13.0-alpine                           
0d2267ul4iv4        dockerregistry_dockerregistry   replicated          1/1                 registry:2                                    *:5000->5000/tcp
4tn5xqbss3i5        kong_dbb                        replicated          1/1                 postgres:9.6                                  
u9xo3prf53v2        kong_kong                       replicated          1/1                 kong:1.1.2                                    *:80->8000/tcp, *:443->8443/tcp
kgmhthn93qwy        saas_thumbsum_0_0_13            replicated          1/1                 metcarob/saas_thumbsum:0.0.13                 
zhyna2ktbgw4        saas_user_management_0_0_66     replicated          1/1                 metcarob/saas_user_management_system:0.0.66
```

I have tried removing and recreating the saas_thumbsum service but this made no difference. (Only altered the ip's in question)

I can supply the saas_thumbsum_0_0_13 nginx config but this hasn't changed since the working version and I don't think this is the problem.

Thanks for any help!

### Update 001 - Extra information

I have exactly the same setup with my saas_user_management_0_0_66 service. This is working without a problem.

```
robert@metcaac4:~$ docker exec -it kong_kong.1.dr5afpgi5me23p96kub2qmjaq /bin/sh
/ # nslookup saas_user_management_system_0_0_66
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

nslookup: can't resolve 'saas_user_management_system_0_0_66': Name does not resolve
/ # nslookup saas_user_management_0_0_66
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      saas_user_management_0_0_66
Address 1: 10.0.0.244
/ # nslookup tasks.saas_user_management_0_0_66
nslookup: can't resolve '(null)': Name does not resolve

Name:      tasks.saas_user_management_0_0_66
Address 1: 10.0.0.245 saas_user_management_0_0_66.1.0092odmxl4er803jhcrad7xhb.main_net
/ # pint 10.0.0.244
/bin/sh: pint: not found
/ # ping 10.0.0.244
PING 10.0.0.244 (10.0.0.244): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.244: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.244: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.244 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.082/0.097/0.113 ms
/ # ping 10.0.0.245
PING 10.0.0.245 (10.0.0.245): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.245: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.177 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.245: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.112 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.245 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.112/0.144/0.177 ms
/ # wget 10.0.0.245
Connecting to 10.0.0.245 (10.0.0.245:80)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
/ # wget 10.0.0.244
Connecting to 10.0.0.244 (10.0.0.244:80)
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

In the above wget to both 10.0.0.245 and 10.0.0.244 give exactly the same 404 not found response from the server.I have no idea why saas_thumbsum gets connection refused.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my own problem. It might be useful to have this post here because someone else may come across the same thing.

I message up and I launched the container with the following command:

```
docker service create --name saas_thumbsum_0_0_13 --network main_net metcarob/:0.0.13
```

When it should have been

```
docker service create --name saas_thumbsum_0_0_13 --network main_net metcarob/saas_thumbsum:0.0.13
```

(Due to using enviroment variables in my auto deploy process)

I don't know why a service launched with no container and I also don't know why one IP worked and the other didn't.
Also I was able to do a docker exec command into the container so something must have been running.

Anyway, it's fixed now!